# Android facebook hash key error - 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: java, android, facebook

I can't generate the key. I get an error

> 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I have this command

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\keytool.exe -exportcert -alias androidfacebook -keystore C:\Users\Jo\Desktop\facebookkey.keystore | c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

Comment: If you want your existing command to work, you can most likely replace the "Program Files" portion with Progra~1, to get the underlying short directory name, without spaces. Assuming the remainder of the command is correct.

Comment: @ahillman3 That fixed it thanks. post it as an answer to i can accept it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your existing command to work, you can most likely replace the "Program Files" portion with Progra~1, to get the underlying short directory name, without spaces. Assuming the remainder of the command is correct.

Comment: Well, that feels a bit hacky. Quoting the path is more common. How do you know whether to use `Progra~1` or `Progra~2`? Which one refers to `Program Files`, and which on to `Program Files (x86)`? Using quotes is somewhat less opaque.

Comment: FYI - open a command prompt and do "dir /X" to get the shortnames.  It can be helpful sometimes.

Comment: It is a bit hacky, and shows my age, that I knew how to resolve. Generally Progra~1 is Program Files unless it is a non-standard Windows install. Glad to see the dir /X as well, brings back ancient memories.

Comment: Some memories are best kept in the past ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Although this is tagged Java and Android, I'm assuming from the command you are executing and the error message that this command is executing on your Windows development machine.

The command line interpretor is regarding the space between `Program` and `Files` as a  delimiter. Wrapping the path in quotes is the normal way to deal with this problem:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your command in `double quotes("")`

```
 "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias androidfacebook -keystore C:\Users\Jo\Desktop\facebookkey.keystore | c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

lets make it easy set your java path as [given here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

then try only this

```
keytool.exe -exportcert -alias androidfacebook -keystore C:\Users\Jo\Desktop\facebookkey.keystore | c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```